# WSL, Running linux commands with "wsl --exec <cmd>" or "wsl -- <cmd>"

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

`wsl -h` shows the following:

```
    --exec, -e <CommandLine>   Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell.
    --   Pass the remaining command line as is.
```

What does "without using the default Linux shell" mean (i.e. what else is it going to use, if not the default shell!?)?.

Additionally, by way of an example, I now have three possible ways to run Linux `ls` from my PowerShell prompt (i.e. this will not be `Get-ChildItem` aliased to `ls`, but instead a Linux command via WSL):

```
PS C:\> wsl -e ls   # Alternatively,  wsl --exec ls
PS C:\> wsl -- ls
PS C:\> wsl ls
```

But all outputs appear to be the same. How would you explain the differences between these three ways of running a WSL Linux command from a PowerShell prompt?

Comment: with wsl ... /bin/bash is used. With wsl -e .... The shell is env. This has more relevance when you are running shell scripts on wsl.

Answer (score 5):

I think it means wsl runs the command `directly`, instead of spawning a shell process to run the command.

For example, if I run :

```
wsl -e sleep 10
```

From another terminal, I have :

```
root      1482     1  0 11:32 tty3     00:00:00 /init
ubuntu    1483  1482  0 11:32 tty3     00:00:00 sleep 10
```

We can see `/init` is the parent of `sleep 10`, without a shell in between.

Answer (score -1):

A cool trick is using this to set the X11 $DISPLAY variable, letting you use windows terminal to get remote shells using WSLG.

```
# in microsoft terminal or powershell use this command line
wsl.exe -- ssh -a -X -Y $hostname
```

then on the remote system

```
# DISPLAY will show something like localhost:10.0 on the remote system
echo $DISPLAY
# use a program like xeyes to test
xeyes
```

Comment: This sounds good, but I tried it and can't get it to work. Where you say `$hostname` I assumed you meant replacing that by the IP or hostname of the remote Linux system, I've tried both ways, and all that happens is that I ssh onto the remote system. Then, `echo $DISPLAY` shows nothing ... Typing `xeyes` results in `Error: Can't open display:`. Are you running on Windows 11? I'm using Windows 10, but I have setup my WSL to support GUI apps, so I thought this should work.

Comment: @YorSubs yes, you need to have Win11, or at least a recently patched windows 10.  
WSLG is in windows 11. 
You need to have WSL2 + WSLG specifically. 
https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/730

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/13041