# My message in assembly when compiled does not display

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm, ld

I'm on Windows 11 in 64 bits and I wrote this code in assembly a64 but after being compiled and linked (with nasm and then ld) it just wait 3sec average and just stop :

```
bits 64

section .data
    message db 'Hello World !', 10

section .text
    global _start
    _start:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, message
        mov rdx, 13+1
        syscall

        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

nasm command typed in powershell : `nasm -f win64 file.asm -o file.o`

then ld command : `ld file.o -o file.exe`

When I start this file in powershell it just wait 3 sec and stop. Same for cmd.

It's a test program for my compiler to see if it works and I don't know if I didn't write correctly the code or if those compiler or linker don't work on Win 11.

Note : also my processsor is an Intel

Comment: Where did you get those syscall numbers?  Looks like linux.  The linux syscalls are not going to work on Windows.

Comment: You might take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/24423642/2189500 (although that's 32bit).

Answer (score 0):

1. Windoze programs [generally] do [not use `syscall`/`sysenter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49956285);
   you usually [use the WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70525769).
2. Apart from adapting the “Hello World” referred to in [David Wohlferd’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70980386/my-message-in-assembly-when-compiled-does-not-display#comment125479081_70980386), you can meanwhile use the WSL, **Windoh’s Subsystem for Linux**, so you can still program with the familiar `syscall` interface.
   Obviously this requires an `‑felf64` executable to begin with, but (without having tried that out) something like [`wsl ‑‑exec myProgram`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66150671) should do the trick then.
3. Some style comment:
   Filling `rdx` with `13+1` is prone to error.
   Use an [`equ` constant](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.4) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Two possibilities:
1.
"The linux syscalls are not going to work on Windows".

> Try it on Linux.

2.syscall instruction use MSR regsisters as target.Traditional eax syscall-number will not work.

> Try replace "syscall" with "int 0x80"

Please provide more infomation

Comment: 1. Yes, this code is using Linux x86-64 system calls.  2. Huh?  No.  Windows doesn't even use `int 0x80` for system calls from user-space, that will just crash on the `int 0x80` instead of returning a "bad system call" error return.  Windows x64 *does* use `syscall` for system calls, with RAX as the call number AFAIK (https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/ / ), so the appropriate MSRs are set up, unlike the IDT entry for `0x80`.  The call numbers [are undocumented and not stable between versions](//stackoverflow.com/q/2489889), and different from Linux; even the available calls differ.